# Stop org-fill-paragraph from joining lines after a list

Tags: org-mode

I use `m-q` in org mode to fill paragraphs.

For the below,

```
- asdf
  asdf
```

When pressing `m-q`, it will be joined together,

```
- asdfasdf
```

Adding a forced newline can avoid that,

```
- asdf \\
  asdf
```

But how to achieve that without adding \\ ?

Comment: My understanding is that `org-fill-element` is the function responsible for it, and it doesn't seem like it can be easily modified to accommodate you.  Even the line-break is hard-coded into it, so you cannot replace it with something else.

Comment: @wvxvw where is the hard coded part in code?

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/org/org.el#L22989 this, I believe.